# Incarnations of Lord Ganesha?

Tags: avatars, ganesha

According to Ganesha Purana, there are four incarnations of Lord Ganesha:

1. **Mahotkata** (Krita Yuga)
2. **Shri Mayureshwar** (Treta Yuga)
3. **Shri Gajanana** (Dwapara Yuga)
4. **Dhuraketu** (Kali Yuga)

According to Mudgal Purana, there are eight avatars of Lord Ganesha:
**Vakratunda, Ekadanta, Mahodara, Gajanana, Lambhodara, Vikata, Vighnaraja, Dhoomravarna.**

Now I am totally confused as to which Purana is right.

Comment: Devatas are Anadi. They are beyond time. Lord Ganesha is symbol of wisdom and vivek. He can incarnate as many times he want.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any problem if both the list are simultaneously correct. :)

For the time being I can give you the relevant verses from the Mudgala Purana. According to this Purana Lord Ganesha took 8 incarnations to kill 8 specific Daityas.

Quoting from the article ["Ganesha Mahima"](https://www.templepurohit.com/ganesha-mahima/):

> Mudgala Purana details various manifestations of Ganesha as of killing
>   Daityas:
>
> Vakratundaavataarascha dehaanaam Brahma thaarakah,
>  Matsaraasura hantaa
>   cha simhavaahanagah smtitah/
>  Ekadantaavataaro vai dehaanaam
>   Brahmadhaarakah,
> Madaasurasya hantaa sa aakhuvaaha -nagah
>   smritah/
>  Mahodara iti khyaato Jnaana Brahma prakaashakah,
>   Mohaasurasya shatruvaim aakhu- vaahanagah smritah/
>  Gajaananah sa
>   vigjneyah saankhebhyah siddhi daayakah,
>  Lobhaasura prahartaa vai
>   aakhugascha prakeertitah/
>  Lambovataaro vai Krodhaasura
>   nibarhanah,
>  Shakti Brahmaakhugah sad yat tasya dhaaraka
>   uchyate/
>  Vikato naama vikhyaatah Kaamaasura vidaahakah,
>  Mayura
>   vaahanash -chaayam Sourabrahmadharah smritah/
>  Vighnaraajaavataarascha
>   shesha vaahana uchyate,
>  Mamata--asura hantaa cha Vishnubrahmoti
>   vaachakah/
>  Dhumra varnaavataarascha abhimaanaasura naashakah,
>   akhuvaahana evaasou Shivaatmaatu sa uchyate ||
>
> **Vakratunda** sporting the back on a roaring lion killed Matsaraasura.
>   Seated comfortalby as a ‘mooshaka vaahana’, the Lord with His
>   **‘ekadanta’** the single tusk destroyed Madaasura. Mooshaka vahana
>   Ganesha as manifested as **Mahodara** killed Mohaasura.Assuming the title
>   of **Gajaanana** killed Lobhaasura while as **Lambodara** destroyed
>   Krodhaasura. The outstanding evil of the Society viz. Kaamaasura was
>   subdued and killed by Ganesha as **Mayura Vahana** while as Sesha Vahana
>   **Vighna Raja** killed Mamataasura. As **Mooshaka Vaahana**, Maha Ganesha
>   destroyed Abhimaanaasura. Thus as Vakratunda-Ekadanta and such
>   ‘avataaraas’, Ganesha destroyed Matsara, Mada, Moha, Lobha, Krodha,
>   Kaama, Mamata and Ahankaara naamaka asuras.

So as Vakratunda he killed Matsarasura, as Ekadanta Madasura etc.

(Note - The author of the cited article is the same person who's books get published on the Kamakoti.org. All the ["Essence of Purana Series"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/puranashome.html) books are authored by him.)