# How many incarnations are there of Lord Ganesh?

Tags: avatars, ganesha

Lord Ganesh is known to be the first worshipped God. Somewhere I have heard that he was present before the marriage of Lord Shiva and Goddess Parvati in some form or incarnation. I want to know how many incarnations does Lord Ganesha has?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incarnations of Lord Ganesha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10066/20129)